# Perl Stack Trace (Devel::Trace)

Tags: perl, stack-trace, trace

I tried `Devel::Trace` to get the perl stack trace by using it as the debugger for the code.

```
perl -d:Trace <pgm>
```

Also tried using `$Devel::Trace::TRACE = 0;` and  `Devel::Trace::trace('on');` within the perl code. But am not able to get the trace.

Can someone illustrate the usage of `Devel::Trace` inside the perl code with an example.

Answer (score 3):

`Devel::Trace` does not produce a *stack trace*. Instead, it prints out the currently executing statement. Example:

```
$ cat script.pl
    use feature 'say';
    my $foo = "bar";
    say $foo;
$ perl -d:Trace script.pl
>> script.pl:2:     my $foo = "bar";
>> script.pl:3:     say $foo;
bar
```

Inside your code, you can turn tracing on and off for certain regions:

```
$ cat script.pl
    use feature 'say';
    my $foo = "bar";
    for my $n (1 .. 3) {
      local $Devel::Trace::TRACE = 0;
      say $foo x $n;
    }
    say "That were some ${foo}s";
$ perl -d:Trace script.pl
>> script.pl:2:     my $foo = "bar";
>> script.pl:3:     for my $n (1 .. 3) {
>> script.pl:4:       local $Devel::Trace::TRACE = 0;
bar
>> script.pl:4:       local $Devel::Trace::TRACE = 0;
barbar
>> script.pl:4:       local $Devel::Trace::TRACE = 0;
barbarbar
>> script.pl:7:     say "That were some ${foo}s";
That were some bars
```

As you can see, the `say $foo x $n` line is not included in the trace output as I turned of tracing inside that scope.

If you want a stack trace (as in “call stack trace”), then use the `Carp` module:

```
$ cat script.pl
    use Carp ();

    foo("Hello World");

    sub foo { bar(@_) }
    sub bar { baz(@_) }
    sub baz { qux(@_) }
    sub qux { Carp::cluck "Howdy!" }
$ perl script.pl
Howdy! at so1.pl line 8.
        main::qux('Hello World') called at script.pl line 7
        main::baz('Hello World') called at script.pl line 6
        main::bar('Hello World') called at script.pl line 5
        main::foo('Hello World') called at script.pl line 3
```

Comment: Thanks! That was really good. Would I be able to print out the currently executing statements without using `perl -d:Trace` ? Would I be able to invoke it within the code ?

Comment: @AmanVidura It is not generally useful to print each statement during normal execution – it's just a debugging help. You could disable tracing at the beginning via `BEGIN{ $Devel::Trace::TRACE = 0 }`, and then re-allow it in the scope where you are interested via `local $Devel::Trace::TRACE = 1`. Anyway, this module relies on the debugging facilities of the perl interpreter, and won't work without debugging enabled – it basically sets a breakpoint before each statement, which reduces performance.